Escape json using Jolt
How can we transform the provided input into the desired output?
The transformation involves escaping the string and converting the attributes to valid JSON format. However, any nested attribute within the 'attributes' key, such as 'attr11', should remain a string instead of being converted to JSON.
Input.json
{
  "id": 67046492,
  "owner": "John Doe",
  "version": 1,
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "id": 219,
      "attributes": "{}"
    },
    {
      "id": 220,
      "attributes": "{\"attr1\":{\"value\":\"7.0\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr2\":{\"value\":\"gdajdas\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr3\":{\"value\":\"Y\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr4\":{\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr5\":{\"value\":\"2\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr6\":{\"value\":\"jjj\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr7\":{\"value\":\"N\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr8\":{\"value\":\"jwidhf\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr9\":{\"value\":\"kncskc\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr10\":{\"value\":\"2\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr11\":{\"value\":\"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"7.0\\\",\\\"key3\\\":\\\"3.5\\\",\\\"key4\\\":\\\"\\\"}\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr12\":{\"value\":\"3.5\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"}}"
    },
    {
      "id": 221,
      "attributes": "{\"attr1\":{\"value\":\"7.0\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr2\":{\"value\":\"gdajdas\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr3\":{\"value\":\"Y\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr4\":{\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr5\":{\"value\":\"2\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr6\":{\"value\":\"jjj\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr7\":{\"value\":\"N\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr8\":{\"value\":\"jwidhf\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr9\":{\"value\":\"kncskc\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr10\":{\"value\":\"2\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr11\":{\"value\":\"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"7.0\\\",\\\"key3\\\":\\\"3.5\\\",\\\"key4\\\":\\\"\\\"}\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"},\"attr12\":{\"value\":\"3.5\",\"actionCode\":\"ADD\"}}"
    }
  ]
}

Expected.json

{
    "id": 67046492,
    "owner": "John Doe",
    "version": 1,
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "id": 219,
            "attributes": "{}"
        },
        {
            "id": 220,
            "attributes": {
                "attr1": {
                    "value": "7.0",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr2": {
                    "value": "gdajdas",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr3": {
                    "value": "Y",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr4": {
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr5": {
                    "value": "2",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr6": {
                    "value": "jjj",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr7": {
                    "value": "N",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr8": {
                    "value": "jwidhf",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr9": {
                    "value": "kncskc",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr10": {
                    "value": "2",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr11": {
                    "value": "{\"key1\":\"2\",\"key2\":\"7.0\",\"key3\":\"3.5\",\"key4\":\"\"}",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr12": {
                    "value": "3.5",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 221,
            "attributes": {
                "attr1": {
                    "value": "7.0",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr2": {
                    "value": "gdajdas",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr3": {
                    "value": "Y",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr4": {
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr5": {
                    "value": "2",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr6": {
                    "value": "jjj",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr7": {
                    "value": "N",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr8": {
                    "value": "jwidhf",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr9": {
                    "value": "kncskc",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr10": {
                    "value": "2",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr11": {
                    "value": "{\"key1\":\"2\",\"key2\":\"7.0\",\"key3\":\"3.5\",\"key4\":\"\"}",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                },
                "attr12": {
                    "value": "3.5",
                    "actionCode": "ADD"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


Hi Rakesh. I wonder if is your platform Apache NiFi?

Yes, We are using platform Apache NiFi.

Then, you might use ReplaceText processor along with Search Value = \\"  and Replacement Value = " or unescapeJson function within a UpdateAttribute processor rather than using JoltTransformJSON.

Yes, I have tried out that approach, but as I mentioned the constraint above in the problem statement. attr11 have value contains the json, which is the inner json. But I want only outer json should convert if any inner json should keep it in a same format.

I know this post is kind of old and you probably have moved on from this but I just came across new json transformation language called jslt which happen to have processor in ApacheNifi called JSTLTransformJSON if you are using version 1.19 and above. Spending sometime to learn the language I found that it can actually solve problems where jolt could not. One of them is this problem using the from-json function and the spec will like this:
{
  "id":.id,
  "owner":.owner,
  "version":.version,
  "lineItems":[for(.lineItems) { "id":.id,"attributes":from-json(.attributes) }]
 }

Actuall, if you dont care about the order the spec can be even shorter:
{


  "lineItems":[for(.lineItems) { "id":.id,"attributes":from-json(.attributes) }],
 *:.
 }

The will give what you are looking for (you can try here):
{
  "id" : 67046492,
  "owner" : "John Doe",
  "version" : 1,
  "lineItems" : [ {
    "id" : 219
  }, {
    "id" : 220,
    "attributes" : {
      "attr1" : {
        "value" : "7.0",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr2" : {
        "value" : "gdajdas",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr3" : {
        "value" : "Y",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr4" : {
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr5" : {
        "value" : "2",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr6" : {
        "value" : "jjj",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr7" : {
        "value" : "N",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr8" : {
        "value" : "jwidhf",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr9" : {
        "value" : "kncskc",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr10" : {
        "value" : "2",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr11" : {
        "value" : "{\"key1\":\"2\",\"key2\":\"7.0\",\"key3\":\"3.5\",\"key4\":\"\"}",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr12" : {
        "value" : "3.5",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "id" : 221,
    "attributes" : {
      "attr1" : {
        "value" : "7.0",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr2" : {
        "value" : "gdajdas",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr3" : {
        "value" : "Y",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr4" : {
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr5" : {
        "value" : "2",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr6" : {
        "value" : "jjj",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr7" : {
        "value" : "N",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr8" : {
        "value" : "jwidhf",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr9" : {
        "value" : "kncskc",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr10" : {
        "value" : "2",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr11" : {
        "value" : "{\"key1\":\"2\",\"key2\":\"7.0\",\"key3\":\"3.5\",\"key4\":\"\"}",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      },
      "attr12" : {
        "value" : "3.5",
        "actionCode" : "ADD"
      }
    }
  } ]
}

Hopefully that will help someone coming across the same problem in the future.
